# Cypress Playground cant find a working selector

Tags: cypress

Cypress playground is unable to find a working selector. I was about to get an xpath to work, but the test doesn't work in FireFox.  Below is the code I am trying to create a selector.

```html
<input name="startDate" ng-hide="dateObj.displayTime" ng-disabled="!isEditable" ng-model="dateObj.moment" moment-picker="dateObj.fullDate" ng-attr-inline="{{displayInline || undefined}}" change="onDateTimeChange(newValue, oldValue)" format="L" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control no-animate ng-pristine ng-isolate-scope moment-picker-input ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-min-date ng-valid-max-date ng-touched" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" max-view="month" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" autocomplete="off" validate="false" keyboard="true" ng-required="isRequired === true" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" required="required" aria-invalid="true" style="" xpath="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have there a lot ID's/attributes to find this element, for example:

```
cy.get('[name="startDate"]').type('02-02-2020');
```

This command will find this element and type `02-02-2020` into that input.

Comment: Unfortunately this finds 6 elements